# MongoDB - How to count subdocuments and group results by date?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I’ve got the structure like this (with some other similar fields):

```
{
    "_id" : 103803,
    "views_count" :  20,
    "views" : [
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-06",
            "count" : 6
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-07",
            "count" : 4
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-08”,
            "count" : 10
        },
    ],
    "applications_count" : 30,
    "applications" : [
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-06",
            "count" : 5
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-07",
            "count" : 15
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-08”,
            "count" : 10
        },
    ],
    ],
    "publication_dates" : [
        "2017-07-06",
        "2017-07-07",
        "2017-07-08",
        "2017-07-09",
        "2017-07-10",
    ],
},

{
    "_id" : 103804,
    "views_count" :  15,
    "views" : [
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-06",
            "count" : 5
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-07",
            "count" : 5
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-08”,
            "count" : 5
        },
    ],
    "applications_count" : 9,
    "applications" : [
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-06",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-07",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "date" : "2017-07-08”,
            "count" : 3
        },
    ],
    ],
    "publication_dates" : [
        "2017-07-05”,
        "2017-07-06",
        "2017-07-07",
        "2017-07-08",
        "2017-07-09",
        "2017-07-10",
    ],
},
```

The result I want to get is something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: "2017-07-05”,
        views: 0,
        applications: 0,
    },
    {
        _id: "2017-07-06”,
        views: 11,
        applications: 8,
    },
    {
        _id: "2017-07-07”,
        views: 9,
        applications: 18,
    },
    ….
]
```

I need to get views and applications count for each date from publication_dates.

I tried with such query, it looks like it works only for first $group, further results are wrong

```
db.job_offer_stats.aggregate(
    [
   {
      "$unwind":"$publication_dates"
   },
   {
      "$unwind":"$views"
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$publication_dates",
         "clicks":{
            "$first":"$clicks"
         },
         "redirects":{
            "$first":"$redirects"
         },
         "applications":{
            "$first":"$applications"
         },
         "views_total":{
            "$sum":{
               "$cond":[
                  {
                     "$eq":[
                        "$views.date",
                        "$publication_dates"
                     ]
                  },
                  "$views.count",
                  0
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":"$clicks"
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id",
         "views_total":{
            "$last":"$views_total"
         },
         "redirects":{
            "$first":"$redirects"
         },
         "applications":{
            "$first":"$applications"
         },
         "clicks_total":{
            "$sum":{
               "$cond":[
                  {
                     "$eq":[
                        "$clicks.date",
                        "$_id"
                     ]
                  },
                  "$clicks.count",
                  0
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":"$redirects"
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id",
         "views_total":{
            "$last":"$views_total"
         },
         "clicks_total":{
            "$last":"$clicks_total"
         },
         "applications":{
            "$first":"$applications"
         },
         "redirects_total":{
            "$sum":{
               "$cond":[
                  {
                     "$eq":[
                        "$redirects.date",
                        "$_id"
                     ]
                  },
                  "$redirects.count",
                  0
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":"$applications"
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "_id":1
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id",
         "views_total":{
            "$last":"$views_total"
         },
         "clicks_total":{
            "$last":"$clicks_total"
         },
         "redirects_total":{
            "$last":"$redirects_total"
         },
         "applications_total":{
            "$sum":{
               "$cond":[
                  {
                     "$eq":[
                        "$applications.date",
                        "$_id"
                     ]
                  },
                  "$applications.count",
                  0
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
)
```

Is it possible to get such results in a single query?

Thanks for any advices.